# Changing dynamic text with external xml file

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I have a very specific task and I can't seem to make it work. 
I have an Animate file with a graphic symbol (named help) which contains a dynamic text area (named help_txt) with some text in it. I want to change it with external xml file.
My Xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<frame>
    <first>Begin your adventure here.</first>
    <second>We continue here</second>
</frame>
```

I uploaded an external XML file in the following way:

```
var myXml:XML = new XML();  
myXml.ignoreWhite = true;  
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();  
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("test_eng.xml"));  
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML)  
function processXML(e:Event):void {  
    myXml = new XML(e.target.data);  
    parsFramText();  
}  
function parsFramText(){  
    help_txt.text = myXml.first.text;  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the event listener for `Event.COMPLETE` after calling the `load` method on the URL Loader class. You should add the event listener first and then call the `load` method.

Also, you just need to access `myXml.first` and that should return the text needed.

Updated your code below:

```
var myXml:XML = new XML();  
myXml.ignoreWhite = true;  
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();  
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("test_eng.xml"));  

function processXML(e:Event):void {  
    myXml = new XML(e.target.data);  
    myLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
    parsFramText();  
}

function parsFramText():void{  
    help_txt.text = myXml.first;  
}
```

Also, you should remove your event listener once the XML is loaded. Do look into some error handling event listeners as well in order to handle failure scenarios.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did what you suggested and also added error handling event listener and it worked perfectly. 
    myLoader.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onError);
    function onError(e:IOErrorEvent):void {
        // Do nothing
    }